# Why I can't remove the button from with right click?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, right-click

I tried to use a bind method to used right click for delete the button 'l' but when I pressed it is not working and also if I put to print a single word like

```
    self.l.bind('<Button-3>',lambda x: print("hello"))
```

If I only tried to print a message it is works but in the other case no.

```
self.l.bind('<Button-3>',lambda x: self.l.pack_forget())
```

Any help ?

```
from tkinter import *

def clamp(lo, hi, x):
    return min(max(x, lo), hi)

class blah:
    all = []
    def MoveWindowStart(self, event):
        self.move_lastx = event.x_root
        self.move_lasty = event.y_root
        self.focus()
    def MoveWindow(self, event):
        dx = event.x_root - self.move_lastx
        dy = event.y_root - self.move_lasty
        self.move_lastx = event.x_root
        self.move_lasty = event.y_root
        self.x = clamp(0, 20, self.x + dx) # should depend on
        self.y = clamp(0, 20, self.y + dy) # actual size here
        self.l.place_configure(x=self.x, y=self.y)

    def __init__(self, root,title, x,y):
        self.root = root
        self.x = x; self.y = y
        self.l = Button(self.root, bd=1, bg="#08246b", fg="white",text=title,height = 5, width = 5)

        self.l.pack()
        self.l.bind('<1>', self.MoveWindowStart)
        self.l.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.MoveWindow)
        self.l.bind('<Button-3>',lambda x: self.l.pack_forget())
        self.all.append(self)
        self.focus()

    def focus(self, event=None):
        self.l.tkraise()
        for w in self.all:
            if w is self:
                w.l.configure(bg="#08246b", fg="white")
            else:
                w.l.configure(bg="#d9d9d9", fg="black")
def newbutton():
        x = blah(root, "Window 1",320, 0)
root = Tk()
root.title("...")
root.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d"%(640, 480, 0, 0))
j = Button(root, bd=1, bg="#08246b", fg="white",text='tifdgfdgdftle',command=newbutton)
j.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pack_forget()` does not work because when you click and drag the button you run the function `MoveWindow()` which uses `place()` instead of `pack()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting self.l.pack_forget as a function, because as of now it isn't in your code...

I'm not too familiar with Python but I think it would go something like this -

```
Function self.l.pack_forget() {
  //your code here
}
```